# SQL Add a prefix to LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, sql

I use following 2 lines to copy an id of a single data in SQL database.

```
$generate_projects_number = 
    "UPDATE `projects` 
        SET `id_project` = LAST_INSERT_ID() 
        WHERE `projects`.`id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$conn->query($generate_projects_number);
```

Right now I have only the same ID number in row `id_project` and I would like to have there for example 2018P4158 (current year, 'P', projects id).

Schem of our projects number: current year, 'P', projects id (example **2018P4158**)

How can I add prefix to the LAST_INSERT_ID() value?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `CONCAT('2018','P',LAST_INSERT_ID())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following using [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
$generate_projects_number = 
    "UPDATE `projects` 
        SET `id_project` = CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), 'P', `projects`.`id`) 
        WHERE `projects`.`id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$conn->query($generate_projects_number);
```

You can set the year yourself (with PHP) or you can use `YEAR(CURDATE())` to get the current year on the database side. You don't need to call the function  `LAST_INSERT_ID` twice since the value `id` should be the same (see your `WHERE` part of the query).

Comment: using projects.id instead of LAST_INSERT_ID() within the concat is a very nice but subtle improvement :)

Comment: Sebastian, does replacing `LAST_INSERT_ID` with `projects.id` makes any improvement on the runtime of the query? I really liked it and wondered your point.

Comment: @TuğcaEker - I don't know if it is a improvement on the run time of the query. Perhaps taking the value there is a little bit faster than calling the function `LAST_INSERT_ID` (again).

Answer (score 4):

You may use `CONCAT()`. It concatenates two or more expressions together.

```
CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), 'P',  LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

For details please see the documentation of your DBMS.

[MySQL Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

[Transact-SQL Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)